# Union of the Product of sets involving intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]} \space [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$

I tried solving this but can't come up with anything concrete. I put a few values of $x$ and to me, it looks like a $y = x^2$ on the Cartesian plane.

How do I provide a well-founded proof for this? And also, does the union of the product of two sets equal the product of the union of each set?

Is the following true? $\bigcup X \times Y = \bigcup X \space \times \bigcup Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just $y=x^2$, it's the set of points below $y=x^2$ and above $y=0$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$.

As most proofs of the equality of two sets go, you need to show containment in both directions. That is, you have to show:

1. If $(a,b) \in \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$, then $(a,b)$ lies below $y=x^2$, above $y=0$, and between $x=0$ and $x=1$. And;
2. If $(a,b)$ lies below $y=x^2$, above $y=0$, and between $x=0$ and $x=1$, then $(a,b) \in \bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1] \times [0,x^2]$.

As for your last question, try to figure out what $\bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [x,1]$ and $\bigcup_{x \in [0,1]} [0,x^2]$ look like individually, then take their Cartesian product. Is it the same as the above?